# react native change state with asyncstorage

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I want to set state in react native with click on button then set in `asyncStorage` and restart to change view but when I use `componentDidMount` it not tru and show error

```
onRadioPressed2 = async() => {
    const Newlanguage ='fa';
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('language',Newlanguage);
    this.setState({language:'fa'});
    RestartAndroid.restart();
};
```

this my function for setState

```
componentDidMount = () => AsyncStorage.getItem('language').then((Newlanguage) => this.setState({ lang: Newlanguage }));
```

in another page check in ComponentdidMount but going error .any one can help me.in simulator its ok but in release app not true

Comment: You might want to make use of redux for accessing the value elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below to add data into **AsyncStorage** storage.

```
onRadioPress2() {
        try {
            const Newlanguage = 'fa';
            AsyncStorage.setItem('language', Newlanguage)
            this.setState({ language: 'fa' });
            RestartAndroid.restart();

        } catch (error) {
        }
    }
```

You can call the function link:

```
this.onRadioPress2()
```

You can retrieve value using the below code:

```
    AsyncStorage.getItem('language').then((Newlanguage) => {
        this.setState({
            language: Newlanguage
        })
    }).done();
```

Your mistake is you are using the wrong name while setting the state.

```
this.setState({ lang: Newlanguage }) --> this.setState({ language: Newlanguage })
```

Comment: and how to check in another component in beginning app?

Comment: Didn't get you.

Comment: I want to use this state in another component for example Home , Product and ..... how to access this state

Comment: AsyncStorage.getItem('language').then((Newlanguage) => {
        this.setState({
            language: Newlanguage
        })
    }).done();

Comment: You can use above code to get value from async. But you cannot use state to another component.

Comment: is this true in.   ComponentDidMount(){ AsyncStorage.getItem('language').then((Newlanguage) => { this.setState({ language: Newlanguage }) }).done(); }

Comment: Yeah, Its true. You can put in compoenetDidMount

Comment: You can accept and upvote the answer if you will a answer of your question.

Comment: it not true in initial app and get error message "Nothing was returned from render" @Nimarlsinh

Comment: You are doing something wrong. This code is alway work for me.